# GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION in webgl in chromebook-samsung

Tags: javascript, html, webgl, chromebook

I am running one app which uses webgl for rendering. In my program , four texture and default framebuffer is being used.

When i resize and render some data on canvas it throwing error

```
 [WeGLRenderingContext]GL_ERROR :GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION :glDrawArray: framebuffer incomplete
```

This error come when `gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)` is called. I am not able to figure put the problem. Can anybody also face this type of problem?

Comment: It appears that the EGL context might be lost post the resize. Have you tried hooking upto the onsurfacecreated event ?

Comment: Are you re-sizing the screen to be bigger/smaller than the frame buffer? Can you please post a description of what you have attached to each frame buffer including depth buffers and/or RGB/RGBA buffers/textures, and their sizes? Are you correctly drawing to the frame buffer before you attempt to resize (I assume yes)?

Comment: I am using default framebuffer.Resizing happening properly. Code contain 5 texture . All deleting and creating with new size on resize .All 5 texture bind with different gl texture(g..TEXTURE0,gl.TEXTURE1....)  Then gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) fn get called and this function throw warning.

Comment: Did you found the solution?